# colocar proyecto Vue 3 en google drive para desarrollar en dos PCS

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Buen dia,

Soy nuevo en esto de VueJs con Firebase, estoy haciendo un proyecto de prueba y todo marcha bien, resulta que seguí los pasos de como instalar Vue CLI, crear el proyecto y conectarlo con Firebase, el cual esta en este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMPHvxqDrVk&t=1007s

Lo hice al pie de la letra y me creó la carpeta "vue" (por lo que entendí así quedó el nombre del proyecto) dentro de system32 en la carpeta Windows

[image: Carpetas VUE JS]

No quisiera tocar nada para no estropearlo pero me gustaría saber si es posible mover el proyecto a Google Drive, el cual me sincroniza con mi cuenta el Codigo y tendría copia de seguridad por si el PC se malogra, también me serviría por el tema de que puedo trabajar desde el laptop, es esto posible?

Comment: Existe algo que se llama GitHub, una solución basada en Git, otra alternativa es GitLab. Git es un controlador de versiones para código fuente, altamente recomendable. Saludos.

Comment: @fredyfx Hola Fredy, como tal puedo trabajar yo mismo en dos PCs? alla hay un editor de texto y compilador para motar el vue, correrlo y luego hacer deploy en firebase?

Comment: ¿Ya investigaste sobre GIT?

Comment: si correcto un controlador de versiones y github vendria siendo como una red social, lo que no vi es algo asi como lo que pregunto, que yo pueda tener un proyecto de vue en dos pcs de tal manera que pueda acceder a ellos, editar y hacer deploy asi como lo hago con visual studio code

Comment: Mejor ven: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol